# HTML in my JS file - Unexpected Token < on line 1 of loadash.js

Tags: javascript, html

**I have reached the final point with one error remaining to construct a sample dashboard with charts using dc.js.  I have encountered an error.**

> Unexpected token < on line 1 for loadash.js.

loadash.js is valid but for somehow Chrome shows it in my root app directory next to index.html and has the exact copy of the source content as my index.html.   In other words,  my loadash, has html content in it.   I am running this app inside AngularJS.

**What is going on here, and how do I fix this?**

**Script Tags at bottom of index.html above closing body tag**

```
<script src="/app/js/crossfilter/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="/app/js/dc.js-3.1.9/dc.js"></script>     
<script src="/app/js/reductio/reductio.js"></script>
<script src="/app/js/requirejs/require.js"></script> 
<script src="/app/js/universe/src/universe.js"></script>
<script src="/app/js/universe/src/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="/app/app.js"></script>
```

**index.html Snippet**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
...
```

**Actual correct loadash.js file**
[image]

**Non actual loadash.js file showing up in Chrome (contents are the html of my home page and AngularJS url is localhost/loadash#!/main,   why is this loadash in my url???)**
[image]

Comment: Lodash methods seems to be used in js files before loading lodash.js files... Did you try including lodash.js in head tag instead of end of body tag

Comment: Unfortunately moving to the head tag brings up mismatched anonymous error with require.js (order of inclusion seems to matter)

Comment: Looks like loadash script tag had to be commented out and I had use a direct path to the module I was requiring in my universe.js file.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `'./lodash'` with `'./app/js/universe/src/loadash'` so that I use absolute paths instead of "relative" path since AngularJS thinks ./loadash is /loadash#! for some reason I don't know why.

Top of universe.js file

```
'use strict'
var module;
var _ = require(['./app/js/universe/src/lodash'], function(module){

});
```

and commenting out   `<script src="/app/js/universe/src/lodash.js"></script>`

like so

at the bottom of index.html

```
<script src="/app/js/crossfilter/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="/app/js/dc.js-3.1.9/dc.js"></script>     
<script src="/app/js/reductio/reductio.js"></script>
<!--script src="/app/js/universe/src/lodash.js"></script-->
<script src="/app/js/requirejs/require.js"></script>   
<script src="/app/js/universe/src/universe.js"></script>     

<script src="/app/app.js"></script>
```

Eliminated all errors present!